# is there a way to calculate KL diverrgence if you have mean and std of two distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, divergence-operator

I have only two information. For an example: N(0,1) and N(0.1,0.2). Is it possible to calculate KL divergence between these two distributions? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Think about it, why would this not be possible? What do we need to compute the KL divergence? All we need is the densities. Since we are dealing with the normal distribution these are defined by the mean and standard deviation (or variance) of the distribution.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

The density function of $N(0,1)$ will be $p(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{{-\dfrac{x^2}{2}}}$ and the density function of $N(0.1,0.2)$ will be $q(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(0.2)}}e^{{-\dfrac{(x-0.1)^2}{2(0.2)}}}$.

The KL distance of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ is given by

$$D(p||q)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)} dx$$

On solving the integral you get the value around 1.22028